# Mediapipe with GPU support for tensorflow ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM

Tags: opencv, bazel, zlib, libpng, mediapipe

#### Objective

I want to install [Mediapipe](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/install) with GPU support for TensorFlow as explained in the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/gpu_support)

#### Steps to reproduce

What I have done is:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/google/mediapipe.git
$ cd mediapipe
$ nano third_party/opencv_linux.BUILD
```

Then I modified the build instructions to the `opencv_linux.BUILD` as I have `Opencv 4.2` installed from `apt`and `OpenCV 4.7` installed from Source:

```
# Description:
#   OpenCV libraries for video/image processing on Linux

licenses(["notice"])  # BSD license

exports_files(["LICENSE"])

# The following build rule assumes that OpenCV is installed by
# 'apt-get install libopencv-core-dev libopencv-highgui-dev \'
# '                libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-features2d-dev \'
# '                libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-video-dev'
# on Debian Buster/Ubuntu 18.04.
# If you install OpenCV separately, please modify the build rule accordingly.
cc_library(
    name = "opencv",
    hdrs = glob([
        # For OpenCV 4.x
        #"include/aarch64-linux-gnu/opencv4/opencv2/cvconfig.h",
        #"include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/opencv4/opencv2/cvconfig.h",
        "include/x86_64-linux-gnu/opencv4/opencv2/cvconfig.h",
        "include/opencv4/opencv2/**/*.h*",
    ]),
    includes = [
        # For OpenCV 4.x
        #"include/aarch64-linux-gnu/opencv4/",
        #"include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/opencv4/",
        "include/x86_64-linux-gnu/opencv4/",
        "include/opencv4/",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "-l:libopencv_core.so",
        "-l:libopencv_calib3d.so",
        "-l:libopencv_features2d.so",
        "-l:libopencv_highgui.so",
        "-l:libopencv_imgcodecs.so",
        "-l:libopencv_imgproc.so",
        "-l:libopencv_video.so",
        "-l:libopencv_videoio.so",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

and I have added the `cuda` build instructions to the `.bazelrc` file:

```
# This config refers to building with CUDA available. It does not necessarily
# mean that we build CUDA op kernels.
build:using_cuda --define=using_cuda=true
build:using_cuda --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA=1
build:using_cuda --crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain

# This config refers to building CUDA op kernels with nvcc.
build:cuda --config=using_cuda
build:cuda --define=using_cuda_nvcc=true
```

and exported TF cuda path as follows:

```
export TF_CUDA_PATHS=/usr/local/cuda-11.7,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu,/usr/include
```

#### Problem

When I try to build Mediapipe using `bazel`:

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --spawn_strategy=local     --define no_aws_support=true --copt -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS     mediapipe/examples/desktop/object_detection:object_detection_tensorflow
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: /home/belal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_belal/31edfeb8b3dba5f154cc8fa7081e1f1f/external/png/BUILD.bazel:8:11: Compiling png.c failed: (Exit 1): crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command (from target @png//:png) external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/png/_objs/png/png.d ... (remaining 41 arguments skipped)
In file included from external/png/png.c:14:
external/png/pngpriv.h:911:4: error: #error ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM "-I (include path) error: see the notes in pngpriv.h"
  911 | #  error ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM \
      |    ^~~~~
Target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/object_detection:object_detection_tensorflow failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 948.218s, Critical Path: 795.79s
```

- `ZLIB` version is `1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.5` installed via `apt`.
- `Libpng` version is `1.6.37-2` installed via `apt`.

Can you please tell me how can I solve this problem?